# Oracle DB link - where clause evaluation

Tags: db2, oracle12c, database-link

i have a DB2 data source and an Oracle 12c target.
The Oracle has a DB link to the DB2 defined which is working in general.

Now i have a huge table in the DB2 which has a timestamp column (lets call it ROW_CHANGED) for row changes. I want to retrieve rows which have changed after a particular time.

Running

`SELECT * FROM lib.tbl WHERE ROW_CHANGED >'2016-08-01 10:00:00'`

on the DB2 returns exactly 1 row after ca. 90 secs which is fine.

Now i try the same query from the Oracle via the db link:

`SELECT * FROM lib.tbl@dblink_name WHERE ROW_CHANGED >TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-08-01 10:00:00')`

This runs for hours and ends up in a timeout.
I read some Oracle docs and found distributed query optimization tips but most of them refer to joining a local to a remote table which is not my case.

In my desperation, i have tried the DRIVING_SITE hint, without effect.

Now i wonder when the WHERE part of the query will be evaluated. Since i have to use Oracle syntax and not DB2 syntax for the query, is it possible the Oracle will try to first copy the full table and apply the where clause afterwards? I did some research but did not find anything which would help me in this direction.

The ROW_CHANGED is a hidden column in the DB2, if that matters.

Thx for any hint in advance.

**Update**

Thanks@all for help. I'll share what did the trick for me.

First of all i have used TO_TIMESTAMP since the DB2 column is also Timestamp (not date) and i had expected to circumvent implicit conversions by this.
Without the explicit conversion i ran into `ORA-28534: Heterogeneous Services preprocessing error` and i have no hope of touching the DB config within reasonable time.

The explain plan btw did not bring much. It showed a FULL hint and no conversion on the predicates. Indeed it showed the ROW_CHANGED column as Date, i wonder why.

I have tried Justins suggestion to use a bind variable, however i got ORA-28534 again. Next thing i did was to wrap it into a pl/sql block (will run in a SP anyway later).

```
declare
v_tmstmp TIMESTAMP := 01.08.16 10:00:00;
begin

INSERT INTO ORAUSER.TMP_TBL (SRC_PK,ROW_CHANGED)
SELECT  SRC_PK,ROW_CHANGED
FROM lib.tbl@dblink_name
WHERE ROW_CHANGED > v_tmstmp;
end;
```

This was executing in the same time as in DB2 itself. The date format is DD.MM.YY here since it is the default unfortunately.
When changing the variable assignment to

```
v_tmstmp TIMESTAMP := TO_TIMESTAMP('01.08.16 10:00:00','DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS');
```

I got the same problem as before.

Meanwhile the DB2 operators have created an index in the ROW_CHANGED column which i requested earlier that day. This has solved the problem in general it seems. Even my original query finishes in no time now.

Comment: It seems likely that the difference would be the only difference between your two queries: the `TO_TIMESTAMP()` function.  Not familiar with the DB link, but I don't understand why you need this?

Comment: I don't have a DB2 instance to test on, but it looks like the data type is different and is possibly causing implicit conversion of the DB2 data and/or a full table scan. Does using `TO_DATE('2016-08-01 10:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` instead help?

Comment: It might be useful to add the execution plan for the link version; particularly the predicate information, to see if it's calling a function against the DB2 table column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are actually using an Oracle-specific conversion function like `to_timestamp`, that forces the predicate to be evaluated on the Oracle side.  Oracle isn't going to know how to convert a built-in function like `to_timestamp` into an exactly equivalent function call in DB2.

If you used a bind variable, that would be more likely to get evaluated on the DB2 side.  But that may be complicated by the data type mapping between different databases-- there may not be a perfect mapping between one engine's `date` and another engine's `timestamp` data type.  If this was a numeric column, a bind variable would be almost certain to get pushed.  In this case, it probably involves playing around a bit to figure out exactly what data type to use for your variable that works for your framework, Oracle, and DB2.

If using a bind variable doesn't work, you can force the predicate to be evaluated on the remote server using the [`dbms_hs_passthrough` package](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_hspass.htm).  That lets you send a query verbatim to the remote server which allows you to do things like use functions defined in your DB2 database.  That's a bit of overkill in this situation, hopefully, but it's nice to have the hammer as your backup if the simpler solution doesn't work quickly enough.

Comment: This put me on the right track, so i mark it as answer. Seems the bind variable will work but might need adaption in the connector config (ODBC in my case)